# Google App Script Data Validation inserts too many dropdowns

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that works mostly the way want. It looks at a cell then compares that to a column in another tab, finds the like items and returns that, and creates a dropdown on the cell. This moves down the column until it reaches the end. The problem is that it continues past the last row for about 20 rows. The starting row is row24.

```
    function getInventoryItems() {
  var jobSummaryInventoryItems = jobSummary.getRange(24, 8, jobSummary.getLastRow(), 1);
  var jobSummaryInventoryItemsValues = jobSummaryInventoryItems.getValues();
  var inventoryItems = inventory.getRange(4, 3, inventory.getLastRow(), 1);
  var inventoryItemsValues = inventoryItems.getValues();
  jobSummary.getRange(24, 8, jobSummary.getLastRow(), 1).setDataValidation(null);
  for (z = 0; z < jobSummaryInventoryItemsValues.length; z++) {
    if (jobSummaryInventoryItemsValues[z].toString().length > 1) {
      var listOfInventory = [];
      for (i = 0; i < inventoryItems.getLastRow() - 4; i++) {
        if (inventoryItemsValues[i].toString() == jobSummaryInventoryItemsValues[z]) {
          break;
        }
        var w = jobSummaryInventoryItemsValues[z];
        if (inventoryItemsValues[i].toString().includes(jobSummaryInventoryItemsValues[z])) {
          listOfInventory.push(inventoryItemsValues[i].toString());
        }
      }

    }
    if (listOfInventory.length > 0) {
      var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(listOfInventory).build();
      jobSummary.getRange(z + 24, 8).setDataValidation(rangeRule);
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Get Inventory Items

```
function getInventoryItems() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const jobSummary = ss.getSheetByName('Job Summary');
  const inventory = ss.getSheetByName('Inventory');
  const jobSummaryInventoryItems = jobSummary.getRange(24, 8, jobSummary.getLastRow() - 23, 1);
  const jobSummaryInventoryItemsValues = jobSummaryInventoryItems.getValues();
  const inventoryItems = inventory.getRange(4, 3, inventory.getLastRow() - 3, 1);
  const inventoryItemsValues = inventoryItems.getValues();

  jobSummary.getRange(24, 8, jobSummary.getLastRow() -23, 1).setDataValidation(null);

  for (z = 0; z < jobSummaryInventoryItemsValues.length; z++) {
    if (jobSummaryInventoryItemsValues[z].toString().length > 1) {
      let listOfInventory = [];
      for (i = 0; i < inventoryItems.length; i++) {
        if (inventoryItemsValues[i].toString() == jobSummaryInventoryItemsValues[z]) {
          break;
        }
        let w = jobSummaryInventoryItemsValues[z];
        if (inventoryItemsValues[i].toString().includes(jobSummaryInventoryItemsValues[z])) {
          listOfInventory.push(inventoryItemsValues[i].toString());
        }
      }

    }
    if (listOfInventory.length > 0) {
      let rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(listOfInventory).build();
      jobSummary.getRange(z + 24, 8).setDataValidation(rangeRule);
    }
  }
}
```

- [Sheet.getRange(row,column,number of rows, number of columns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))